# Why is that the result of my first array is repeated instead of getting the 2nd user

Tags: php

1st

which shows an output of

Msg Ardy Button
Msg Ardy Button
Msg Ardy Button
Msg Ardy Button
Msg Ardy Button
Msg Ardy Button
Msg John Button

```
<?php 

include('connection.php');
$sqlsearch = "SELECT * FROM chat WHERE recievernumber = $empnumnum and Notification = '0' ORDER BY chat_id ASC";
$resultsearch = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlsearch);
if ($resultsearch->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row

while($rowsearch = $resultsearch->fetch_assoc()) { 


echo " 
  <tr>

    <td>$rowsearch[msg]</td>
    <td style='list-style-type: none; color:white;' class='chatlist' data-employeeid='".$rowsearch['employeeid']."' data-fullname='".$rowsearch['user']."'> $rowsearch[user] </td>
    <td><button class='chatlist' data-employeeid='".$rowsearch['employeeid']."' data-fullname='".$rowsearch['user']."'>Read</button></td>    
  </tr>";                                                                     

}
}
?>
```

So I tried to remove multiple Ardy Msgs so I use the code below.
but the result was. The only correct thing that happened was the employee id. Because it has foreach ($id2 as $value) I was Thinking if I can use 2 foreach to solve it. But I don't know how.

Msg John Button 
Msg John Button

2nd

```
<?php

$sqlsearch = "SELECT DISTINCT  * FROM chat WHERE recievernumber = $empnumnum and Notification = '0'";
$resultsearch = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlsearch);
if ($resultsearch->num_rows > 0) {
while($rowsearch = $resultsearch->fetch_assoc()) { 
$id = $rowsearch['employeeid'];
$id1[] = $id;

$name = $rowsearch['user'];
  $name1[] = $name;
  $msg = $rowsearch['msg'];
  $msg1[] = $msg;


}
$id2 = array_unique($id1);
foreach ($id2 as $value){


echo " 
  <tr>

    <td>".$msg."</td>
    <td style='list-style-type: none; color:white;' class='chatlist' data-employeeid='".$value."' data-fullname='".$name."'> $name </td>
    <td><button class='chatlist' data-employeeid='".$value."' data-fullname='".$name."'>Read</button></td>    
  </tr>";                                                                     
}
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the structure of the table `chat`, what row(s) exist for the first user and what is your desired result table?

Comment: Are you expecting just 1 row in your result table for the first user?

Comment: `DISTINCT *` won't return distinct rows by user ID (you specified all columns) - This might help - http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx. Please show sample input (a small representative sample), actual output and desired output.

Comment: you haven't stripped the data - just a security heads up

Comment: Its okay. Thanks for the effort tho. Thanks a lot man!